# ¿Como cambiar el alto del p a la fuente su hija/hijo TextNode?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Lo que pretendo hacer es que el p tenga la misma altura y anchura que su hija. Intenté esto:

```js
const p = document.querySelector("#p");
p.style.height= getComputedStyle(p).fontSize;
```

```css
#p{
  position: absolute;/*Hacer que el p tenga la misma anchura que su hijo*/
}
```

```html
<p id ="p">Texto</p>
```

Pero su altura sigue siendo la del p, no la de su hijo. Entonces abrí la consola y vi que al escribir document.querySelector("#p"); me mostraba sobre el texto, dos bordes amarillos y uno azul que cubria toda el textNode y que juntos los tres formaban el alto del p.

Se me ocurrio borrar la parte azul asi:

```js
const p = document.querySelector("#p");

p.style.height = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(p).height) - 2 - parseFloat(getComputedStyle(p).fontSize) + "px";
```

```css
#p{
  position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<p id ="p">Texto</p>
```

Que hace que el alto del p sea menor, pero no igual a su hija. Así que el problema estaría en eliminar las dos partes amarillas que la consola muestra sobre el p, pero no sé como se hace ni si se puede.

¿Cómo lo harían ustedes?

Muchas gracias!

Comment: El hijo del p, que sería el texto que lo contiene, y si voy a la consola y pongo document.querySelector("#p"); , me selecta el p entero y se ven como un fondo de azul y amarillo

Comment: ¿Será que lo que necesitas es ponerle `margin: 0` al `<p>`?

Comment: Gracias era eso! Jajaja

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los navegadores por defecto agregan estilos a algunos elementos.

Para que alto de "[la caja](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/The_box_model)" del `<p>` sea exactamente igual al tamaño del texto, tendrías que asegurarte de "resetear" todos los estilos que pudiera tener y que afectan al tamaño de su caja.

#### Ejemplo:

```js
const p = document.querySelector("#p");

console.log('<p>', parseFloat(getComputedStyle(p).height) + 'px');
```

```css
#p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<p id="p">Texto</p>
```